# Number of web browser instance testng

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

When i run my tests under testng multiple instance of browser are launched and then tests starts

this is my testng.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="tst.TST4"/>
            <class name="tst.TST3"/>
            <class name="tst.TST2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <!-- Test -->
</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

i have a lot of tests to do so do you think it's normal that for 1000 tests testng will open 1000 instance of browser and then start tests?

Comment: Yes. You should have one browser instance per test. That browser should be opened at the start of the test and closed at the end of the test. Is that what you are asking? If so, this isn't a programming question but instead a testing/QA question. If that's not your question, you need to edit your question and clarify what you are asking. Where is your code that launches the browser, starts a test, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in every test method you create a new webrdiriver instance (like `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`. It's a little resource cost if you have a lot of tests. 
Try to create setUp() and tearDown() methods where you prepare and clean your data before each test.

So it'll look like this:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class SearchText(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Firefox session
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # navigate to the application home page
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: i have set up and teardown methodss in my test       public void setUp() throws Exception {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }      and tear down methode              public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }